# How I can count the number of times a value appears in a column grouped by day?

Tags: mysql

My table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `survey` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `submitdate` datetime default NULL,
 `answer` varchar(5) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=499 ;
```

Here `answer` contains values such as a1, a2, a3.

I want to calculate the last 10 days records depending upon answer. Is there is no record on a particular day, it should be zero.

The output I want is

```
date         count answer
19-11-2012      10    a1
19-11-2012       8    a2
19-11-2012       0    a3
18-11-2012      30    a1
18-11-2012      30    a2
18-11-2012      30    a3
```

I used a query like

```
SELECT days.day, count(survey.id)
FROM
  (select curdate() as day
   union select curdate() - interval 1 day
   union select curdate() - interval 2 day
   union select curdate() - interval 3 day
   union select curdate() - interval 4 day
   union select curdate() - interval 5 day
   union select curdate() - interval 6 day
   union select curdate() - interval 7 day
   union select curdate() - interval 8 day
   union select curdate() - interval 9 day) days
  left join survey
   on days.day = date(survey.submitdate)
group by
  days.day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look back 10 days by using the SUBDATE function and compare dates using '>'. You'll also want to GROUP BY the answer as well as the day, since you're attempting to calculate the count of each individual answer per day.

```
SELECT DATE(submitdate) AS day
answer,
COUNT(*) AS answer_count
FROM survey
WHERE DATE(submitdate) > DATE(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 10))
GROUP BY day, answer;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it doest work with no records on that particular day.

Comment: Do you have an answers table that keeps track of all possible answers?

Comment: desired example answers table also mentioned in question.